# Route Conflict Between WebAPI and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Only when I deploy (not in dev mode on iis express) do I get a route conflict between webAPI and MVC routing.  The MVC route is the one I want, however I don't see how the WebAPI route is possible.  My code below is wat I have in my WebAPIConfig which to me means there is no /Home route there.

I just updated to MVC5 and The latest WebAPI.  I did not have this issue previously.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());

 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
    ("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
        new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
    ("API Default Rest", "rest/{controller}/{urlPart}",
    new
    {
        urlPart = RouteParameter.Optional
    });

 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
    ("API Default RPC", "rpc/{controller}/{action}/{urlPart}",
    new
    {
        urlPart = RouteParameter.Optional
    });
```

ERROR:

Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter. The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers: WebAPI.Controllers.HomeController WebApplication3.Controllers.HomeController

The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:
WebAPI.Controllers.HomeController
WebApplication3.Controllers.HomeController

Comment: What was the route that you requested?

Comment: / or /home was what I requested

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was an "old dll" problem.  I removed all files from the site, published again and it works now.

Comment: I had a similar issue and the fix was to manually delete the bin and obj folder because the clean was not doing that properly in VS2017.